# Делимость чисел

Tags: python-3.x

Входные данные:  На вход программа получает два натуральных числа, каждое не больше 100

Выходные данные:  Программа должна выводить число 1, если одно из чисел делится на другое. В противном случае необходимо вывести любое другое число не равное 1, и не превосходящее 10**9.

Запрещенные операторы: if;for;while;do;max;min.

Пример:

Входные данные: 2 4 Выходные данные: 1
Входные данные: 4 2 Выходные данные: 1
Входные данные: 5 2 Выходные данные: 500

Как такое решить? В голову ничего не приходит.

Comment: Укажите примерные свои мысли. Как вы думаете будет работать логика математического решения. Какие правила существуют для определения делимости одного числа на другое. Как бы вы реализовали данную логику с помощью Python

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Советую вам прочитать о том [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Вам следует добавить в вопрос код, имеющийся на данный момент у вас, либо ваши мысли и идеи по поводу возможного решения проблемы, чтобы вопрос не был т.н. "Домашним заданием"

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(a, b):
    return (a % b and b % a) + 1
    
print(check(2, 4));
print(check(4, 2));
print(check(5, 2));
print(check(2, 5));
```

```js
function check(a, b) {
  return (a % b && b % a) + 1;
}
console.log(check(2, 4));
console.log(check(4, 2));
console.log(check(5, 2));
console.log(check(2, 5));
```